# HTML/CSS Input focus outside range

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I have a form on my websites and for some reason there are some space which after clicking them automatically focus to the fields on in the second column. I tried to find any element which could cause it but without any luck. I have never seen any behaviour like this.

You can see the form here: Doesn't exist anymore

Any help would be nice.

If you need to see the css I can provide a sass version:

```
@keyframes input-underline {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  50% {
    left: 0;
    right: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
  }

  51% {
    background: $secondary-color;
  }

  100% {
    background: $secondary-color;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}

.contact {
    form {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;

        label {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;

            &::before {
                position: absolute;
                content: '';
                bottom: 0;
                height: 2px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                transition: background .6s linear;
                background: #ccc;
            }

            &.active {
                &::before {
                    animation: input-underline .6s linear forwards;
                    background: #ccc;
                }

                .input-label {
                    top: -16px;
                    font-size: .925rem;
                }
            }

            .input-label {
                position: absolute;
                top: 7px;
                left: 0;
                transition: top .15s linear, font-size .15s linear;
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }

        .input {
            display: block;
            background: transparent;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 0;
            border: none;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-weight: $global-weight-light;

            &.textarea {
                min-height: auto;
                height: 38px;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 154px;
                resize: none;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
        }

        .select, .submit {
            appearance: none;
        }

        .submit {
            display: block;
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 260px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #1d1d1b;
            background: $secondary-color;
            color: $white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Full code here: Doesn't exist anymore

JS code here: Doesn't exist anymore

EDIT: I use the ZURB Foundation, in case it's important.
EDIT: The links provided aren't working anymore, so I deleted them.

Comment: Do you have any HTML?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I marked the spaces in the image above. I actually asked more people to try it on multiple PCs and they all had the same problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE0oQ.jpg

Comment: I got it... That is why I removed my comment. That is strange, I agree.

Comment: @JamesDouglas You can see the HTML via View Source in your browser.

Comment: strange never seen anything like that either

Comment: Related to `.row::after {
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
}` ?? Try to remove that. In `style.css`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Could you make it as answer? I'll check it as accepted. And thanks.

Comment: ;) okay !!! Sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you wrap all your `<div class="row">` in a `<div class="table">`.

And then use this CSS:

```
.table{
  display:table;
}
.row{
  display:table-row;
}
.row div{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

And get rid of :

```
.row::before,
.row::after {
  display: table;
  content: ' ';
}
```

Comment: Yeah, problem is  that this is part of the Foundation framework... But anyway I just added this: .contact .row::after {content: normal;} and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ho... I see. Well, I'll leave my answer as is... Since this is it way it should be. But your comment is usefull as a fix to this "Foundation" issue.